# noun-adjective pattern

Tags: grammar

寒い国に生まれたからといって、寒さに強いわけではない. can anyone explain this pattern  寒さに強い, noun に adjective , how to use it and which nouns,adjective can be used in this form ?

Answer (score 3):

「に」in this sentence is just the preposition "to", as in "resistant to cold"